# How to select mysql database table from a dropdown list to insert record

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to select a mysql database table from a dropdown list to insert a new record in my database. How can I do that ?. in the picture below, I am using category to select a table in database. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried and what your specific problem is.

Comment: right now I am using separate pages to insert record into the tables of my database for example I have 4 tables in my database (World, Sports, Entertainment & Lifestyle) what now I have is separate pages like world_insert_post.php,  sports_insert_post.php, entertainment_insert_post.php, lifestyle_insert_post.php. The Code on each page is too long so I guess I am not able to post it in the comment box. What I want is to have single page to insert record and a dropdown list option where I can select my database table where I can insert new record. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a value of this field corresponding name from database, for example:

```
<select name="table_db">
<option value="user_table">Users</option>
</select>
```

Then in PHP script just use your $_POST['table_db'] to get name of table, but ofcourse you need to escape it before use:

```
$table_name = $_POST['table_db']; //escape it here!!!
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name;";
```

That's all.

Comment: you said _but ofcourse you need to escape it before use:_ How to do that ?

Comment: It depends which DB you are using?